# Javascript redirect based on date

Tags: javascript, date, redirect

I want the user to be directed to bar.html on the first of the month, gjb.html on the second of the month, guerr.html on the third of the month and error.html on other dates.

What am I doing wrong? The following only loads bar.html regardless of the date on the user's computer.

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    currentTime = new Date();
    if (currentTime.getDate() = 1)
        window.location = "bar.html";
    else if (currentTime.getDate() = 2))
        window.location = "gjb.html";
    else if (currentTime.getDate() = 3))
        window.location = "guerr.html";
    else window.location = "error.html";
</script>
</html>
```

I'm brand new to all this, so explain it like you would to a total idiot.

Comment: Take a look at your console, it should say something like _ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment_

Answer (score 3):

Just needs to be a proper equality check, not the assignment operator you are using:

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var currentDate = new Date().getDate();
    if (currentDate === 1)
        window.location = "bar.html";
    else if (currentDate === 2))
        window.location = "gjb.html";
    else if (currentDate === 3))
        window.location = "guerr.html";
    else window.location = "error.html";
</script>
</html>
```

I suggest `===` over `==` because that does a proper type check, and you are guaranteed to get Integers so this is a safer check. When in doubt, `===`.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the date with `currentTime.getDate() = 1`.  Try `currentTime.getDate() == 1` or `currentTime.getDate() === 1`. (I dont use js all the time, but '=' is wrong).

Answer (score 1):

try using double equals (==).  The single equals operator signifies assignment while the double equals signifies a comparison.

Example:

// Assign a value to a
int a = 1;

// Assign a value to b
int b = 2;

// See whether or not a is equal to b

```
if( a == b ) {
        System.out.println("They're equal!");
}
else {
         System.out.println("They're not equal!");
}
```