# Is it possible to do redirection based on time?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

Is it possible to redirect to another URL for certain time, for example from 06:00 to 08:00, and for the rest of the day some other URL.

Comment: Yes. What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Date object and get the time and then match it against your desired time and put it in `if` block with above condition, and use something from below

```
// similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
```

or

```
// similar behavior as clicking on a link
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
```

Also see: [Javascript redirect based on date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650118/javascript-redirect-based-on-date)

Answer (score 2):

HTML / JavaScript does not provide such type facility to redirect page in between time but you can apply trick using JavaScript, see sample code

```
var hours = new Date().getHours();

if(hours >= 6 && hours <= 8){
  window.location.href = "some_url";
}else{
  window.location.href = "some_other_url";
}
```

Comment: should it not be a <= for 8 ?